# Sound driver for motherboard gigabyte ga-g1975x-c (Creative Sound Blaster Live 24-bit) (alsa, ca0106)

Tags: drivers, sound, alsa

My motherboard is gigabyte ga-g1975x-c with integrated audio "Creative Sound Blaster Live 24-bit".

I have installed Ubuntu 10.10, and there was no sound at all.

Alsa drivers was already installed.
Finally after long searching, i have found how to make my sound work.

```
/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf:
options snd-ca0106 subsystem=0x10121102 //i have added this line and restart
```

After restarting my speakers and microfon works fine.

Maybe somebody knows different/better subsystem code for my sound card???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudoedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` change or add the following line:

```
options snd-ca0106 subsystem=0x10121102
```

and your sound should work.